# How is Python blocking signals while os.system("sleep...")?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, signals

When I run this Python script with `os.system` on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
import os, signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, lambda *args: os.write(2, 'HANDLER\n'))
print 'status=%r' % os.system('sleep 5')
```

, and then I send SIGABRT to the script process many times within 5 seconds, I get the following output:

```
status=0
HANDLER
```

This indicates that the signal delivery was blocked until `sleep 5` exited, and then only a single signal was delivered.

However, with `subprocess.call`:

```
import os, signal, subprocess
signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, lambda *args: os.write(2, 'HANDLER\n'))
print 'cstatus=%r' % subprocess.call('sleep 5', shell=True)
```

, all individual signals are delivered early:

```
HANDLER
HANDLER
HANDLER
cstatus=0
```

To distinguish the magic in glibc from the magic in Python, I rewrote the Python script in C, so `os.system` became *system(3)*:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
static void handler(int signum) { (void)signum; write(2, "HANDLER\n", 8); }
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int got;
  struct sigaction sa;
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);
  sa.sa_handler = handler;
  if (0 != sigaction(SIGABRT, &sa, NULL)) return 3;
  got = system("sleep 5");
  return !printf("system=0x%x\n", got);
}
```

Signals got delivered early:

```
HANDLER
HANDLER
HANDLER
system=0x0
```

So I inferred that the magic is in Python 2.7, not in eglibc. But where is the magic? Based on the strace output and looking at the `posix_system` function in `Modules/posixmodule.c`, I couldn't figure out how Python blocks the signal until `os.system` returns.

Relevant code from `Modules/posixmodule.c`:

```
static PyObject *posix_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
  char *command;
  long sts;
  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s:system", &command)) return NULL;
  Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
  sts = system(command);
  Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS  
  return PyInt_FromLong(sts);
}
```

Maybe the magic is in `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS`?

Do I understand correctly that it's impossible for my Python signal handler (set up by `signal.signal`) to execute until `os.system` returns?

Is it because signal handlers are blocked (on the Python level, not on the OS level) until `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` returns?

Here is the strace output of the Python code with `os.system`: http://pastebin.com/Wjn9KBye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Maybe the magic is in PY_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS?*

The magic is mostly in [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) itself.  `system` cannot return EINTR, so the libc implementation goes to pains to resume its `wait`'ing on the child process.  That means in your use of `os.system`, control never returns to python until the underlying `system` completes, and thus the python signal handling mechanics aren't invoked timely.

`subprocess.call`, however, is essentially doing this:

```
# Compare subprocess.py:Popen/_eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
while True:
  try:
    return os.waitpid(the_child_pid, 0)
  except OSError, e:
    if e.errno == errno.EINTR:  # signal.signal() handler already invoked
      continue
    raise
```

Here control *does* return to python when the underlying `wait` is interrupted.  The OSError/EINTR prompts python to see if any signals were tripped and, if so, to invoke the user-supplied code block associated with that signal.  (And that's how the interpreter adapts the system's signal semantics:  set a flag, and check it between "atomic" python operations, invoking the user's code if appropriate.)